# google play console "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (4800403)"?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-api, google-play-console

i did a transfer for my app from an account google play developer to another one , but when i tried to edit my game details this error shows "An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. (4800403)" , any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

its like they didn't complet the transfer steps (or i must do them myself) so what i did is sign in to https://console.developers.google.com with the old account email and then i added the new account email as an owner and thats gave me the rights to do whatever i want to my game in my new account developer console , to finish the relation with the old account i removed its email from https://console.developers.google.com using my new account as owner